# Wordpress Images not resizing correctly

Tags: wordpress

Recently, some of the images on one of my wordpress sites stopped being display correctly or consistently. For example, [Bombardier Battery Range](http://vta-sprinter.org/2015/11/08/bombardier-battery-range/). Basically this text magically appears after an image.

```
 600w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" />
```

When I google this error, I find tons of other websites with the same problem, making it hard to find a discussion of the issue.

I can cure this specific instance by resizing the first of the two pictures to make it below 600x300.  However, going back and shrinking dozens of images doesn't seem to be a wise decision.

This started with some upgrade during the past two weeks.  Unfortunately, from a troubleshooting perspective, I have the same plugins on other sites that haven't started to manifest this issue -- yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the full HTML source of your page, you will see the `<img>` tags are shown as:

```
<a href="http://vta-sprinter.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Track-Pedestals-02.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-590" 
src="http://vta-sprinter.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Track-Pedestals-02-300x200.jpg" alt="Track-Pedestals-02" 
width="338" height="225" srcset="http://vta-sprinter.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Track-Pedestals-02-300x200.jpg 
300w, http://vta-sprinter.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Track-Pedestals-02.jpg 650w, 
http://vta-sprinter.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/<span id=" eeb-443657"=""><script 
type="text/javascript">(function(){var ml="pkfs-4ro3cPtAECge.Fda%jT0lxDnh2im",mi="E8>DENHM6@2E8KENNPDOI;7E8<G6D914:@C@3;DI34HN48HHJNHHE5HNJAF0?ENNENHENH9ID33E8KENNPDOI;74IOL1ENNE8=G6D914:@C@3;DI34HN48HHJNHHE5HNJAF0?E8>ENBDE8=",
o="";for(var j=0,l=mi.length;j<l;j++){o+=ml.charAt(mi.charCodeAt(j)-48);}document.getElementById("eeb-443657").innerHTML
 = decodeURIComponent(o);}());</script><noscript>*protected email*</noscript> 600w" sizes="(max-width: 338px) 100vw, 338px" /&gt;</a>
```

In the middle of that mess, you will see `<span>` and `<script>` tags that appear to be obfuscating all email addresses in the code.

You have two options to fix the issue:

1. Disable the email encoding plugin that you're using (such as something like [Email Address Encoder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-address-encoder/) plugin); OR
2. Install the [Disable Responsive Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-responsive-images/) plugin (or something similar), which will disable the responsive images

Edit: It's possible the WP-Retina-2x plugin you're running on the site might be generating the `@2x` images, so it might help to disable that plugin also.

#### Additional Details

The email address encoding plugin is incorrectly assuming that any `@` mentioned in the code is an email address. In this case however, it's a Retina image, which has the `@2x` suffix:

```
Track-Pedestals-02@2x.jpg
                  ^ -- The confused @ symbol
```

You would have only just started noticing this issue recently, as WordPress 4.4 introduced the new [responsive images support](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/).

Comment: I disabled the email encoder for now -- and the problem has disappeared.  Thank you for the very informative response.